# Android listView really slow with background Image

Tags: android, performance, listview, background-image

I have the following problem: I am using a regular ListView with a themed background image which gives me really big performance headaches. When I remove the window (see themes.xml) background image, everything is butter smooth. With the background image it is noticeably slower.

I already tried:

- android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
- listview.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);

But nothing worked. I don't understand why this is so slow, because the ListView is just plain white - shouldn't be a problem ...

theme.xml:

```
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/window_bg</item>
```

list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="10dp">
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you applying your background for every list item (in the custom adapter) or to the listview as a whole?

Comment: currently I set the background color to every list item. 

I removed it in the list items because it was unnecessary, but still the same performance issue

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a white background, then see if you can just set the background color to white instead of using a drawable. Things will speed up instantly!

Comment: I know, but I need a image background for all my activity windows and on top of that a listview. Actually that shouldn't affect the performance of the listview, because the complete listview has a white background.

Comment: are you using custom adapter for listview ?